# iOS password to be able to use the app?

Tags: ios, iphone, password-protection

I am making a small app for my colleagues and myself that will contain some calculation tools some manuals and some drawings...

I would want them to be able to download the app from the apple store but since we do not want anyone to have access to the information in the app, I would like only the people with a password to be able to open it and use it.

I don't really want to go the adhoc way, some people are not particularly tech-savvy and I want to keep it as simple as possible...

Neither do I want to distribute the app through an enterprise account..

So is it possible to restrict the access of an app with a password stored locally?
Does Apple allow this?

Basically the first time the app opens, the user will be prompt a view with a password to enter, if he knows it then the app is somehow activated otherwise you can't open it....

Comment: It is likely that Apple would reject your app and point you towards an enterprise distribution.

Comment: that's what I was afraid of... thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I could recommend using TestFlight as a solution. I'm not sure if you're familiar with it but it is part of developer tools. You can give target people codes based on their iTunes account or their unique phone identifier.

If that helps at all let me know! :)

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not clearly stated I think that your app could get rejected if people do not have a possibility to "create an account" and use your app.

An excerpt:

> Also, remember that not everyone using your app has an account from
>   the start. Make sure you explain how to get one, or provide a simple
>   in-app way to sign up.

Here you can find some more information:
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/interaction/authentication/

Comment: Thank you, I will explore the adhoc way then!